# Multiple tags for 'The Hobbit'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

With the release of *The Desolation of Smaug*, do we need multiple tags for the three Hobbit films? (I'm guessing that we do.) If yes, how do we go about retagging [all the questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit)?

Answer (score 1):

[desolation-of-smaug](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desolation-of-smaug)
[unexpected-journey](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unexpected-journey)
[there-and-back-again](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/there-and-back-again)

For the Hobbit specific movies.

[fellowship-of-the-ring](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fellowship-of-the-ring)
[the-two-towers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-two-towers)
[return-of-the-king](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-king)

For the Lord of the Rings specific movies

[the-hobbit-trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit-trilogy) For anything Hobbit related as a SERIES.

[lord-of-the-rings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) For anything LotR related as a SERIES.

Comment: 1. Will users be able to find `desolation-of-smaug` when they try to add 'the-hobbit-desolation-of-smaug` (or its shorter form)? 2. Can we merge `the-hobbit` with `the-hobbit-trilogy`? This should make things a little easier.

Comment: There are other "The Hobbit" movies out there which is why I'm against blanket merging.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There are other LotR movies out there too. Are you suggesting that a potential question from the new film will have to be tagged with _the-hobbit_, _the-hobbit-trilogy_, and _desolation-of-smaug_?

Comment: No, thats nonsense.  The point is to tag each individual movie with say *desolation-of-smaug* for the Hobbit movie released in 2013, *the-hobbit-trilogy* apply when talking about *all 3 movies together*, and *the-hobbit-year* when talking about the earlier Hobbit works

Comment: Then shouldn't there be a `lord-of-the-rings-trilogy` tag? When would `the-hobbit` tag then be used? And which tag would I then use if I wanted to locate all questions about `the-hobbit`? To exemplify, I can locate all questions on Star Trek by simply clicking the `star-trek` tag.

Comment: What about `the-desolation-of-smaug` and `an-unexpected-journey`? Are they too long (at least the second one doesn't seem to, but I'm too lazy to count and maybe you already did)? If not, we should rather do it properly instead of creating another such fiasco as the `dark-knight` tags.

Comment: lord-of-the-rings-trilogy is just short enough to work.

Comment: @TylerShads Yet *nobody* wants that `-trilogy` in there anyway (letting my subjective opinion speak for everybody, of course). ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau Apparently, we are using `hobbit-2` now  :|

Comment: @coleopterist Yeah, that's bad. I'd have liked to see `the-hobbit` *together* with *Tyler*'s suggested individual tags.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian states in the comments to Tyler's answer, we should probably use:

1. [an-unexpected-journey](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/an-unexpected-journey)
2. [the-desolation-of-smaug](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-desolation-of-smaug)
3. [battle-of-the-five-armies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-of-the-five-armies)

I'm pretty sure that there's a meta post that states that we should always try to include the article in the tag name. We can probably synonymise [the-hobbit-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit-1), [the-hobbit-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit-2), and [the-hobbit-3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit-3) to these tags to assist users.

I don't think that we have a policy on "trilogy" tags. They don't exist for questions about the Matrix or LotR trilogies. But we do have one for Raimi's Spiderman trilogy.

I'd prefer to retain [the-hobbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) tag for questions about any version of *The Hobbit*. The [the-hobbit-trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit-trilogy) tag can probably wait for now.

Comment: Trilogy tag are very useful when we talk about full universe but for hobbit the need for it appear to be little far.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure that there's a meta post that states that we should always try to include the article in the tag name."* - [Indeed there is](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1027/49) (even if that's just the opinion of a single misguided individual ;-)).